# merging mutlidimensional array together to have a continous key

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

i want to merge this two arrays together

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => Person
            [relevance] => 0.700000
            [count] => 300
            [text] => Chris
        )
)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => Person
            [relevance] => 0.900000
            [count] => 400
            [text] => Chris
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => Person
            [relevance] => 0.500000
            [count] => 200
            [text] => Tom
        )
)
```

so i might have a result like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => Person
            [relevance] => 0.900000
            [count] => 400
            [text] => Chris
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => Person
            [relevance] => 0.500000
            [count] => 200
            [text] => Tom
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [type] => Person
            [relevance] => 0.700000
            [count] => 300
            [text] => taye
        )
)
```

Comment: [`array_merge`](http://php.net/array_merge)?

Comment: please kindly look at the desired result. i want the first array layer to keep its key while the others should continue from the last key of the first array layer. like 0, 1, 2 not 0, 0, 1 i'm talking about the keys. thanks

Comment: also assume that this array results are coming from the database and it is assigned to a variable so if i perform the loop test how can i merge it to get the desire result above

Comment: Now you've just made it more complicated instead of clarifying it. `array_merge` is perfectly suited for what you want to do. *Unless* you literally mean that array keys need to "continue after the last key of the first array". What if the first array has the keys `2`, `3`?

Comment: deceze you just got the question.

Comment: Why didn't you write that *in the question?!*

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
$array_final = array_merge($array_1, $array_2);
```

refer [array_merge](http://php.net/array_merge) at official documentation site

Comment: array_merge works if you know the number of the variables to merge but lets assume you getting the multidimensional array result from the database you know there won't be a specific amount or number to merge how will you now merge the them together with you not having a clue of the number of the multidimensional array result you will get. thanks

Comment: If every array is in an array for example, you can use like this: `$array_final=call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array_of_arrays);` Or if you are fetching them row by row, then you can append them one-by-one  like this: `$result_array=array_merge($result_array,$new_array);`

Comment: Lajos Veres you are the man. just figured it with the example you gave. thank you so much. +1 for you men. just a simple line just nearly made Olympus to fall.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `foreach`

```
// $array1 is your original array
foreach($array2 as $val) {
     array_push($array2,$val)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array_merge [docs](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.array-merge.php) and is faster to check documentation:D

Answer (score 0):

Did you search the PHP Doc ?

what about [array_merge_recursive](http://php.net/array_merge_recursive) ?